# Persistence of Swedish special chars in 2 Microsoft SQL Server behaving differently?

Tags: sql, sql-server, special-characters

I came across a weird situation with two instances of SQL Server 2019 running on two different pre-production environments (exactly the same codebase). I'm trying to persist the following Swedish sentence as a `nvarchar(200)`:

```
Förlängd livslängd BFS9
```

Problem is that when I check one instance of SQL Server 2019, it gets persisted without recognizing those special chars:

[image]

When I check the other pre-prod environment SQL Server 2019 instance:

[image]

This is causing on the affected pre-prod env a:

> Invalid Unicode escape sequence

error obviously.

I've checked for both all available collations by doing a

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations();
```

and they share exactly the same rows (seem also having all the Finnish, Swedish collations, 5508 rows are returned), what can be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not use images for code, data or errors. Use formatted text.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand for your answer. The persistence logic inserts the string as : N'Förlängd livslängd BFS9'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `nvarchar() COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked and compared server, database, table, column, connection collations?

AutoTranslate feature of the SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver?
You can also see what values are stored after cast to `varbinary(max)`. I found more than once tons of stupid animals in plain text like this.